# Select and replace field of key referenced by environment variable with special character using jq

Tags: json, environment-variables, jq

Given the json below:

```
./versions.json

{
  "my-app-1": "v1.0.0",
  "my-app-2": "v0.9.1",
  "my-app-3": "v2.1.7"
}
```

I want to replace the version of `$APP_NAME` to the new version `$NEW_VERSION`. Given `APP_NAME=my-app-2` and `NEW_VERSION=v1.0.0`, I tried the following:

```
jq '(."$APP_NAME") = "$NEW_VERSION"' ./versions.json > updated_versions.json
```

which gives:

```
./updated_versions.json

{
  "my-app-1": "v1.0.0",
  "my-app-2": "v0.9.1",
  "my-app-3": "v2.1.7",
  "$APP_NAME": "$NEW_VERSION"
}
```

this:

```
jq "(.$APP_NAME) = \"$NEW_VERSION\"" versions.json > updated_versions.json
```

gives:

```
jq: error: app/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
(.my-app-1) = "v1.0.0"
jq: 1 compile error
```

How can I escape the special character in the environment variable? I have tried setting `APP_NAME=my\\-app\\-1` with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: for your consideration, here's an _alternative_ solution for the JSON manipulation in your question - based on a unix _walk-path_ utility **`jtc`**: `APP_NAME='my-app-2'; NEW_VERSION='"v5.0.1"'; <version.json jtc -w"<$APP_NAME>l" -u"$NEW_VERSION"` - Let me know if you're interested - I can elaborate on the tool usage in a separate answer. (PS. I'm a developer of the tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the two variables to `jq` using its `--arg` option :

```
jq --arg appName my-app-2 --arg newVersion v1.0.0 '.[$appName]=$newVersion'
```

In your first try the `jq` command was enclosed in single-quotes, so it was left to `jq` to resolve the variables, but it doesn't look for them in the outer shell context.

Your second try was nearly good (but not very good practice) because the variables were expanded by the shell, but `my-app-1` contains special characters (the dashes) and needs to be accessed with either `."my-app-1"` or `.["my-app-1"]`.

Comment: It would be good if you can explain why OP's attempt didn't work using shell variable names directly under `'..'` won't work

Comment: thank you very much. 
`jq --arg appName $APP_NAME --arg newVersion $NEW_VERSION '.[$appName]=$newVersion' versions.json` > updated_versions.json`